# psql is still pointing to older version after upgrade to newer ( 10.7 )

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

I have 2 different major versions of postgres 9 and 10 installed on rhel.

Latest situation after attempts of updating psql package:
I have psql 9.2.24 installed on rhel 7.6 while the server version is 10.7.
I had earlier issues with my yum repo which got corrupted and later on, i recovered/fixed it with the help of following command mentioned at [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1091450/centos-7-2-yum-repo-configuration-fails) (You can get idea of what my problem was initially with corrupt yum repo)

```
echo 7 > /etc/yum/vars/releasever
```

I checked my update-alternatives at [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/618435/which-package-to-upgrade-psql-client)
and it is correctly referring to the psql at 10.7 directory but still I am seeing the psql old version number while connecting to existing database.

Following was the steps i followed to update the psql package:

---

1. All databases were kept running.
2. yum install postgresql10.x86_64
3. Command mentioned in point 2,  installed/upgraded whole lot of packages on machine as the yum repo was corrupted . one of the key statements in this upgrade concerning to postgres was

> postgresql10   x86_64  10.7-2PGDG.rhel7 pgdg10 1.6M

Please note, I have not yet restarted any of the instance running during/before/after above update  <s>and somehow believe it has something related to the fact that until I restart(stop existing instances and start them again) all running instances of psql/db's , psql changes will not start reflecting but that is just my assumption.</s> Could someone please help what i understood/did wrong in this upgrade process.

Nothing except above has been changed/upgraded in terms of psql/postgres. Still I have both installations of postgres: 9 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

I did this fix few months back and I forgot that. Something similar with better answers are at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052046/how-do-i-correct-the-mismatch-of-psql-version-and-postgresql-version) So all credits goes to answer posters there. But here is what I did to solve it:-

1. Restarting already running postgres instances did not help.
2. I checked `which psql` showed me one of the psql at `/usr/bin` . It was some 9 months old so definitely it was not something got installed with my `yum postgres...` install step mentioned in my question which made me realize that new package installation will not override it straightaway.
3. I tried using 
   `update-alternatives --config pgsql-psql` but got the same error as mentioned on the above SO answer:
   `/usr/bin/psql exists and it is not a symlink`
4. key clue on this page is in the comment from @Alexander Gorg that `ln` command will not override the existing link , it needs to be removed manually.  I thought of removing the symlink but then end up renaming the psql at /usr/bin to psql_org.
   Indeed i issued `ln` command during this process.
5. Now i issued the update-alternatives command and restarted one of the instances. Correct psql was now there.

Above indeed helped fixing psql version but still other utilities pg_basebackup and others were referring to older version. I believe better approach would have been to remove the old postgresql installation. I tried to list existing postgresql version with

```
yum list installed | grep postgres
```

only shows that

```
postgresql10*
```

packages are there and I remember I have already removed older postgres version with 
`yum erase postgres...` so not sure what to remove.

Temporarily I have further solved issued by renaming other utilities in /usr/bin and then updating their alternatives.