# When trying to get the source of a function in Postgres using psql, what does the error "column p.proisagg does not exist" mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, psql

**Background**:
using postgres 11 on RDS, interface is psql on a Centos 7 box; objective is to show the source of certain stored procs / functions so that I can work with them

**Problem description** : When I attempt to list / show the source of a given stored function using the `\df+` command which I understand to be correct for this use based on [official docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html], an error is given as shown:

```
psql=> \df+ schema_foo.proc_bar;
ERROR:  column p.proisagg does not exist
LINE 6:   WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
```

I have no clue how to interpret this; the function in question does not contain the snippet of logic shown in the error, nor the column referenced there `p.proisagg`.  I have verified this by opening the function in vim with `\ef`.

My guess based on several unrelated github issues that mention this same error [for example](https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/issues/537) is that it is in reference to some schema code internal to postgres.

**Summary**: in short, I can view the source of the functions using `\ef`, so my work is not impaired from a practical standpoint, however I wish to understand this error and why I'm encountering it with `\df+`.

Comment: you are using an outdated `psql` version against a newer Postgres (server) version

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks a bunch @a_horse_with_no_name .  This led me to another mini-difficulty of not being able to figure out how to get psql to run as version 11 [which is installed on the centos box as well as rds, but the psql symlink was out of date for some reason and wouldn't update manually via ln ] -- solved with answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052046/how-do-i-correct-the-mismatch-of-psql-version-and-postgresql-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and ran these 2 commands to fix it

```
sed -i "s/NOT pp.proisagg/pp.prokind='f'/g" /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/classes/database/Postgres.php
sed -i "s/NOT p.proisagg/p.prokind='f'/g" /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/classes/database/Postgres.php
```