# Is there any alternative to the ```\d+``` to describe database schema in PGSQL 14?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-14

I want to describe a table schema in postgresql 14.
However when I use the older `\d+`, the error is thrown:

```
pgsql=# \d+ <table_name>
ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you use an older `psql` version to connect to a newer server version, some commands may fail, as `psql` informs you when the connection is established. This is exactly what you see at work there.

Call the `psql` from your v14 installation, and things will work fine. If you don't know how to do that, uninstall all older versions of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

`\d+` is working on Postgres14 well. Maybe you are use older version of `psql`. There is not forward compatibility. If you want to use PostgreSQL14, you should to use `psql` for Postgres14 and higher.
You can check it by `--option`:

```
[pavel.stehule@pgsql ~]$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Like both the earlier answers, you have two versions of **psql** in your host and the default is the older one which is not compatible with the current database version which is 14.

**Temporary fix**:

- verify the current version & location

```
bash-4.2$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24
bash-4.2$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
```

- Find the location of the version of psql for the current DB.
  Usually, its under /usr/psql??/bin , like:

```
bash-4.2$ cd /usr/pgsql-13/bin
bash-4.2$ ls -ltr|grep psql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  644264 May 13  2021 psql
```

- Navigate to that location or invoke that psql binary by providing the path, like

```
bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3

bash-4.2$ /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql
Pager usage is off.
psql (13.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

**Permanent Fix**

If you want the **psql** of the existing database which is the new version to be default , you can use  'update-alternatives' utility. Like mentioned here:
[How do I correct the mismatch of psql version and postgresql version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052046/how-do-i-correct-the-mismatch-of-psql-version-and-postgresql-version)

This is how I did.

```
    
    [root@ip-10-211-209-252 bin]# pwd
/usr/bin
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]# mv psql psql9
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/psql psql /usr/bin/psql9  1
    
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]# cd /usr/pgsql-13/bin
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]# ls -ltr|grep psql
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  644264 May 13  2021 psql
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/psql psql /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql 2
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]# update-alternatives --config psql
    
    There are 3 programs which provide 'psql'.
    
      Selection    Command
    -----------------------------------------------
    *+ 1           /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql
       2           /usr/bin/psql
       3           /usr/bin/psql9
    
    Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1
    [root@ip-xxxx bin]#
```